# android best practice to store non-displayed information in views

Tags: java, android

I have a listView where each line represents part of the information of a row of a database. With onItemClick the user can select an item in the list and a new activity will start.

```
id    first_name    last_name     address     ....
__________________________________________________

1          Peter      Griffin  Rhode Island   ....
```

When switching to the new activity I would like to pass on the id in a bundle so that I can easily identify in the next activity what item was clicked.

I am just wondering what the best way is to link the id to the item in the listView which only displays the name. I can come up with various ways, but they all give me the feeling that there should be some better way to do it.

1.) view.setTag()
I don't understand what the intention behind that tagging is. Tagging each view with the id would solve my problem, but it seems very opaque

2.) manual layout with 'invisible' field
I could make the child views manual and add a second field with 0 width that could contain the id. Seems very hacky, though

3.) When populating the array that contains the rows for the listView, simultaneously populate another array with the ids in the same order so that the position variable in the onItemClick method would get me the id as well. Seems like a better way then the above, but I still don't feel it's the best way.

I know, best practice is a subjective concept and there may be no clear answer, but any pros and cons would be appreciated to help me get a better idea of how to do things in a good way.

Comment: Are you using cursor adapter?

Comment: I use an array adapter. Don't know cursor adapters. Need to read up on that

Comment: You can keep a variable in your model as id . you can retrieve this id from onitemclick.

Comment: So, that would be along the lines of what I described as 3.) ?

Comment: As per your idea it will be in a different array right? As per  My suggestion it will be inside your model for each row.

Comment: I don't follow you. Do you mind explaining with a brief example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112550/discussion-between-krish-and-chrise).